# Route or base_url is not working properly in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm currently developing my personal blog, but I have problem with my route. Let's say that I have a contoller named

**Blog**

```
<?php 

class Blog extends CI_Controller {
    public function index(){
        $data['posts'] = $this->BlogModel->get_post();

        $this->load->view('frontend/header');
        $this->load->view('frontend/navbar');
        $this->load->view('frontend/BlogContent',$data);
        $this->load->view('frontend/footer');
    }

    public function view($slug = NULL){
        $data['post'] = $this->BlogModel->get_post($slug);

        if(empty($data['post'])){
            show_404();
        }

        $data['title'] = $data['post']['title'];

        $this->load->view('frontend/header');
        $this->load->view('frontend/navbar');
        $this->load->view('frontend/blog/view',$data);
        $this->load->view('frontend/footer');
    }
}
?>
```

my route is like :

```
$route['blog/(:any)'] = 'blog/view/$1';
$route['default_controller'] = 'home';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

then I tried access this part http://localhost/cathode/blog/post-one is working properly

but while tried to access navbar menu after access those part, my base_url is included 'blog' controller.

[blog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nll6m.png)

so while I tried to access 'home' menu, the route will direct to http://localhost/cathode/blog/home, and actually my base_url is http://localhost/cathode/, How can I solve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Please share your `$config['base_url']` , `$config['uri_protocol']` , `$config['index_page']` values

Comment: $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/cathode/';  $config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';  $config['index_page'] = ''; this one right? @DaniyalNasir

Comment: Can I see the html of navbar with appended base_url.

Comment: <li class="nav-item ">
        <a class="nav-link" href="<?php base_url();?>home">HOME <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="<?php base_url();?>about">ABOUT</a>
      </li>  @DaniyalNasir

Comment: Your **Blog** is your controller name so it should be `<a class="nav-link" href="<?php base_url('Blog/home');?>home">HOME <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the given information with little assumptions, I think you're making your navbar like:

```
<a href="home">Home</a>
```

Whereas, you must add the **`base_url()`** like this:

```
<a href="<?= base_url('home'); ?>">Home</a>
```

Let me know, if you have some problem.

### Update

From the provided HTML code:

```
<li class="nav-item "> 
    <a class="nav-link" href="<?php base_url();?>home">
    HOME <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
    </a> 
</li> 
<li class="nav-item"> 
    <a class="nav-link" href="<?php base_url();?>about">ABOUT</a> 
</li>
```

**Replace** `<?php base_url(); ?>`

**To** `<?php echo base_url();?>` **OR** `<?= base_url();?>`

Comment: Pleased to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to add an `echo` before the `base_url()` like this :

```
...
<li class="nav-item "> <a class="nav-link" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>home">HOME <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a> </li>
<li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>about">ABOUT</a> </li>
...
```

Comment: hi @Hasta thanks a lot, this one is also solving my problem :)